# SED find lines with 0.0% // ignore lines with 100.0%

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

i need to "find" all lines with exact this number:  `0.0%`  but in my file are also numbers like `100.0%`

how can i "say to sed" find me EXACT `0.0%` and ignore `100.0%` 
something like this:  `[0].[0]%`

my favorit cmd:

```
more input.txt |  sed -n '/0.0%/p' > output.txt
```

inside my file are lines like this:

```
0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```

thanks for help, i know, thats basic stuff but,....  ;-)))

Comment: about your favorite cmd, it can be shrink down by just `grep '0.0%' input.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use word boundary here:

```
sed -n '/\b0\.0%/p' file
3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss (...)
```

Or else

```
sed -n '/\<0\.0%/p' file
```

Or using `grep:

```
grep '\b0\.0%' file
```

`\b` or `\<` are word boundary that will make sure there is a word boundary before `0.0%` hence avoiding `100%` from match results.

Comment: actually a grep is enough. not sure whether op is aware of grep.

Comment: Yes right, I just added `grep '\b0\.0%' file` to my answer.

Comment: YES, i did it wrong  with the  \    ...............  
grep '\b0\.0%'  <-  that works. thank you so much!!

Comment: done - (thx, it was my first posting here,. next time i`ll click fast on that button ;)